# parent link opens href

Tags: tree, parent-child

I have a nested tree menu and at present, if I click on a parent node that has children it exposes the child nodes,

```
<ul id="menu" role="tree">

<li><a href="course/01_00_00_Getting Started.htm" target="ifrm">Getting Started</a>
  <ul>      
    <li><a href="course/01_00_00_Questions.htm" target="ifrm">Questions</a></li>
    <li><a href="course/01_01_00_Considerations.htm" target="ifrm">Considerations</a></li>
    <li><a href="course/01_02_00_Changing Perspective.htm" target="ifrm">Changing Perspective</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**BUT** I also want the parent node to open an href, not just expose the child links.
Using the above example, when I click on the text 'Getting Started', I want the accompanying href to open the page (pages are opening in an iframe) **AND** expose the child links in the menu.

What do I need to do to incorporate this dual functionality? Or can someone please point to a functional example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following two lines to the click handler on `li`

`var anchor = ele.find('>a');
 if(anchor.length > 0) {
   a.click();
 }`

where ele is `$(evt.target)`